# Can someone look at my private Soundcloud embed and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, soundcloud, sharing

I tried following SoundCloud's advice and linked a private soundcloud player (simple HTML iframe) with a simple .htaccess authentication script. No problem there.

Apparently though, a couple people that have been sent the link are having no joy. I've reviewed the script and tried replicating the problem, but am missing something. Here's the relevant areas of code. The iframe is a part of a very basic table:

```
"<iframe width="500" height="500" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%123456789%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-GggGG&color=F9DAE8&auto_play=true&show_artwork=false" ></iframe>"
```

Comment: Hey, could you please be more specific? What is that you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to hide particular page with SoundCloud Widget behind simple HTTP authentication? How are you using `.htaccess`? What's not working exactly?

Comment: Hey @gryzzly .. I'm using .htaccess do a very simple authentication on the directory in which this HTML page is located. `
AuthType Basic
AuthName "I/T"
AuthUserFile /home6/istropic/preview_auth/.loggedusers
require valid-user`   - like so. I was just wondering if this could interfere with the SoundCloud secret token system, and to check if my iframe was formatted correctly. It seems that people are either having a problem with the initial authentication (in which case it's not my problem) or the widget itself.

Comment: FYI all I'm trying to achieve is a 'preview' page that members of the press can stream the album alongside some pertinent information I've included such as tour dates and what-have-you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your embed code is not correct. The iframe's src in your example is the following (formatted for readability):

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/
?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%123456789 <- missing `%2F`
%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-GggGG <- url-encoded delimiters `?` and `=`
&color=F9DAE8
&auto_play=true
&show_artwork=false
```

A couple of problems:

1. I am sure you just missed it when editing playlist ID for publishing it here, but between `playlist` and its ID (`123456789` in your example), there should be `%2F`, which is url-encoded `/` character.
2. when passing parameters, delimiters (`?`, `=` and `&`) shouldn't be url-encoded (only values of parameters should be)
3. You should use `&` as delimiter after the first URL paramater and not `?`, so the secret token should be delimited with `&`

So, in the end it should be (without the line breaks of course):

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/
?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F123456789
&secret_token=s-GggGG
&color=F9DAE8
&auto_play=true
&show_artwork=false
```

Comment: Thank you I've addressed these. That helps alot. So besides this you can't see any reason why someone wouldn't be able to view the SoundCloud player on my page?